# Pixy Pet Robot stuck on uploading code

Tags: arduino-ide, uploading

when I upload the code to my leonardo board it just stuck on uploading, like this:[image]

could someone help me with this?

Comment: Is it a real Leonardo or a clone? If a clone, adding a reference would be welcome. Also, is it really connected to COM4?

Comment: I am sure it is connected to COM4. Actually, I use SparkFun RedBoard instead of Leonardo, but I also try to use Arduino Uno, it has the same problem.

Comment: First off, the sparkfun redboard  must be defined as a UNO in Arduino IDE, not Leonardo. Second; it uses FTDI drivers: did you install these?